# Change Icon Size in Nautilus Sidebar

Tags: nautilus

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.
Does anyone out there know of a way that I can change the size of the icons in the nautilus sidebar? For example, the icons that appear next to the items in "Places", "Devices", and "Network"? Thank you for your time.